# (w+x)-(y+z) operation with half adder and half subtractor

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit

I can't seem to solve this problem. Already, I'm little confused because of using half adder and half subtractor. I have tried to draw then stuck. How can I make the operation by half adder and half subtractor ? Could someone explain me solution ?
Operation is $$ (w+x)-(y+z) $$
[image]

Comment: Start with a truth table. Perhaps it is **two** half adders an d a subtractor?

Answer (score 1):

For subtraction operation one has to add 2's compliment. you would require Cout to be connected to  inverter and add 1 carry. 
I dont suppose just two half adder would do even if it were simple addition..what to do with Carry output?
vtingole